How to update a variable value with a new value if conditions are met?
I want to create a simple calculator for a simple challenge I found on the internet which calculates the tip you leave for a bill depending on what the value of that bill is, if its between 50 and 300 the tip percentage should be 20%, otherwise it should be 15%.
I want to change the current value of X with the new value inside my If statement once the conditions have been met but after I run the code the initial value is taken.
I've tried to define X inside the IF statement but still not working.
Can somebody help me with a hint to what I'm doing wrong so I can fix it by myself?
Thank you!
let bill = 300;
let x = 0;
let percentage = x;
let tip = (percentage / 100) * bill;
if (bill >= 50 && bill <= 300) {
x = 20;
else {
x = 15;

and I've tried it like this:
let bill = 300;
let percentage = x;
let tip = (percentage / 100) * bill;
if (bill >= 50 && bill <= 300) {
let x = 20;
else {
let x = 15;


You're missing } to match the {; this should have caused a syntax error.

But you need to move all the calculations that use x to after the if/else statement.

Why do you need two variables, x and percentage? Changing x won't change percentage.

Follow what @Barmar said All calculation After if else statement and no need for percentage variable

The issue is that you are trying to calculate the tip percentage too early.  Assigning x to percentage does not mean it updates percentage's value when x is updated.  It will just be whatever x was when you assigned it. Even if it worked like that, you are calculating the tip before the percentage would change.
All the logic is there, it just needs to be put in the right order!
Also: If x is supposed to be equal to percentage, why have two variables?  I think that is making the problem harder for you to conceptualize.

Thank you,
I've moved the tip variable after the if statement and now it works, the extra x variable was a mistake of mine.
But I got the concept now!
